# Padding issue in search box under the more Stack Exchange communities

Tags: bug, design

There is a little padding design issue:

[image]

The search box padding should be `padding: 0px 10px;` instead of `padding: 8px 10px;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubermeta dupe [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307223/369403).

This is a Firefox issue, that has been fixed in the latest version of Firefox. Update your browser, and the text will no longer be clipped.